# ssh server alternative for remote terminal e.g like putty work

Tags: ssh, remote, remote-management

As per my knowledge, [putty](http://www.putty.org/) is the best solution for the remote terminal but we need run the **ssh server** on Linux.

In my case, I want to take Linux remote terminal on Windows machine but do not want to install the ssh server on Linux.

I am searching on google but not find any method for remote terminal without ssh server.

So my Question is there any way to take Linux terminal on windows without **ssh server.**

Comment: i try to understand your question but for some reason i couldn't understood what you want to achieve !

Comment: Which do you actually want?  A remote desktop? A remote terminal?  Or remote management?  They, if one is actually serious about them, have forms that do not involve SSH, and already have questions and answers here.  (Note that _I want to use SSH but I have arbitrarily on a whim decided not to run an SSH server._ indicates a less than serious approach.)  Or are you unaware of the distinctions and all those tags do not _actually_ apply?  If so, again: Which do you actually want?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαηI want to take Linux machine on windows same way as putty works.but the issue with putty I need start ssh server on Linux. due to low memory and small processer when I start ssh server on Linux machine system start hanging.I just want Linux remote terminal on windows without starting ssh server.

Comment: If you don't want to use an `ssh` client to connect to a running `ssh` server, you can use an `rsh` client to connect to a running `rsh` server, or a `telnet` client to connect to a running `telnet` server.  If you want to connect to a remote machine without the remote running *any* server listening for inbound connections and offering a shell, there's not much of a solution.  `telnetd` would probably have the smallest resource requirements.

Comment: @JdeBP I want remote terminal without run ssh server on the remote machine.might be unaware of tags.please suggest me relevant tags and how to take remote terminal without running ssh server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a debian-based system, install `telnetd`, if you are on a Suse/RedHat/Oracle Linux system, install `telnet-server`.

Note, however, that all communications between your Windows system and the Linux box are in the clear, including usernames and passwords!!! Anybody who can intercept the network packets will be able to logon to your telnet server as well ...

OpenSSH is really not that resource hungry, by today's standards, and you should NOT use telnet, imho. If you have any influence on the design/features of the linux system, ensure it has sufficient resources to run OpenSSH, else your company will make the head lines of a new security breach ... just saying. Getting an embedded system with enough resources to run OpenSSH is cheap, really, don't save on the wrong ends!